# how to view docx, xls, xlsx in browser using laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5, doc

**I am using the below code. but still it's downloading the files instead of viewing.**

```
public function viewFiles(StoreBusinessDevelopment $request, $file, $id)
{
    $businessDevelopment = BusinessDevelopment::select('created_by', 'rfp_id')
                                                ->where('id', '=', $id)
                                                ->get();

    $mimeType = File::mimeType(public_path('/uploads/'.$businessDevelopment[0]['created_by'].'/'.$businessDevelopment[0]['rfp_id'].'/'.$file));

    return response()->file(public_path('/uploads/'.$businessDevelopment[0]['created_by'].'/'.$businessDevelopment[0]['rfp_id'].'/'.$file),[
        'Content-Type' => $mimeType
    ]);
}
```

Comment: you can't, no browser supports those formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert files to PDF format and then return it to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Browser unable to read `.doc|xls|xlsx` files. But you can view / rander it by using some tricks.

### Example 1

First upload the file like i say `.doc|xls|xlsx` and make it as array of data. By using php -> laravel that have a module/repo for excel file read and parse it as array. 
After make it as array and print this array as html table and browser must rander it.

For more info : 
[Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)